# Ошибка "Unresolved reference: R"

Tags: android, gradle

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Скажу сразу: - я абсолютный ноль в андроид разработке. 
Получил вот такую ошибку "Unresolved reference: R". Пробовал чистить, ребилдить, синхронизировать с Gradle, инвалидейтить кеш. Ничего не помогает. Я так понимаю, что мой проект не видит файл с ресурсами. Не знаю почему так произошло. Ведь до этого проект запускался без этой ошибки, а после выхода и входа в андроид студию появилась она. Как ее решить??

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ru.temocenter.temocenter"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    } }

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'

    // 3rd party libs
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0' }
```

Comment: причин много может быть покажите логи

Comment: Build -> Clean Project, затем Build -> Rebuild Project

Comment: @Cypher, сейчас прикреплю фото к вопросу.

Comment: @mit, все это делал. И ничего не помогло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я решил этот вопрос. В общем, я просто удалил все те файлы на которые была ругань, сделал билд, посмотрел, что все работает, и добавил их снова - и все работает. Не знаю почему так происходит.

Answer (score 1):

**import android.R**

Удалите эту строку. Она может быть лишней, не знаю откуда взялась

Answer (score 0):

Так вам Android Studio подсказывает почему не может проект билднуть. В `Android Issues` показано в каких файлах есть ошибки. К примеру в вашей разметке `activity_contact_detail.xml` используется файл под названием `shadow` и т.д , но 
 не может его найти из-за этого и происходит ошибка

Comment: Да, я это прочитал. Но файл там есть и в нем нет ошибки. Проблема в том, что он так говорит про почти все файлы, которые у меня есть в drawable, хотя раньше все билдилось и я в них не лазил. Значит дело в механизме, которые как-то цепляет эту папку resource к проекту. Я так думаю. Но не знаю, как этот механизм настроить.

Answer (score 0):

Была похожая ситуация. Возникала при добавлении новой активити. Решалась следующим образом: **File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart... -> Invalidate**, затем **Close Project**, затем удаляем его из списка, затем открываем заново. Где-то на просторах **StackOverflow** это решение описывалась - не могу найти линк. В конечном итоге всё решилось тем, что я перешёл на бета версию AS и проблема исчезла. Однако при очередном обновлении всё повторилось вновь.